# publishing extension create personal access token group marketplace missing

Tags: visual-studio-code, marketplace

I ran into a problem following instructions given at
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension
however, shown group **Marketplace** isn't available.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9PH7.png)

I just started my **azure with github** experience.

tried to follow instructions given at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the image on the linked page you see the scopes have a scroll bar.

On your image there is a **`Show all scopes`** button. Click it and scroll.